# SQL strict enforce of order by a date column

Tags: sql

I have a table(say TableA) with the following schema

```
A(int)    B(int)    D (varchar)    C(date)
```

If I write the query

```
select A, C from TableA where A >=0 order by A asc, B asc, D asc, C asc.
```

The last row of the query will have the C date column which is largest ( I mean here the latest which is greater than all the other dates).
Is that correct?
I have verified with a small query to the table but wanted to verify, to enforce a strict ordering  according to the date query is this the only option

```
select A, C from TableA where A >=0 order by C asc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order-by precedence is left to right so, if you want date to be the major sort field, the following is required.

```
select A, C from TableA where A >=0 order by C asc, A asc, B asc, D asc
```

That second query you gave does it in date order, but you've lost all the other sort criteria.